# Zend Framework 2 and SELECT count(*) query

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to do a query like this using Zend Framework 2:

```
SELECT count(*) as num FROM mytable
```

Here's the code I'm using to build my select statement (bear in mind I've imported the necessary classes):

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('mytable')
       ->columns(array('num'=>'count(*)'), false);
```

This code doesn't work because the resulting query is as follows:

```
SELECT [count(*)] AS [num] FROM [mytable]
```

...which throws the following error:

```
Invalid column name 'count(*)'
```

This is caused by the square brackets around count(*). How can I get this to work properly, basically to have count(*) instead of [count(*)] in the SQL. Also, I know that you can do it with just a regular query, but I need this to work with the Select object. As far as I know, this used to work with the previous versions of Zend, I've seen plenty of solutions for those, but nothing for Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Somebody on another forum was kind enough to give me the answer for this. This is how it's done:

```
$select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, without `new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')`, just `COUNT(*)` leads to the following error statement:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'albs.COUNT(*)' in 'field list'

Having the

```
new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')
```

resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code?

```
$this->num = $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));

return $this->num;
```